# I have problems rendering my comment form on my template in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

Hi guys i have been looking at trying to integrate a simple comment form on my blog project using Django but the form never shows on my template. Please take a look at my code and tell me whats wrong
I need to know how to combine Detail view and FormView so that I can render on the same template

COMMENT FORM(forms.py)

```
from django import forms
from .models import Comment


class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('comment',)
```

VIEWS.PY

```
    from django.views.generic import (ListView, DetailView,FormView)
    from .import models
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.template import RequestContext
    from .forms import CommentForm

    class EntryDetail(DetailView):
        model = models.EntryPost
        form_class = CommentForm
        template_name = "post.html"

        def comment_valid(request, form):
            if request.method == "POST":
                comment_form = form_class(request.POST or None)
                if comment_form.is_valid():
                    comment = comment_form.cleaned_data['comment']
                    comment.save()
                    return super(EntryDetail).comment_valid(form)
                else:
                    form = CommentForm()
                return render(request,'post.html',{"form":comment_form,})
```

FORM TEMPLATE

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{# {% load django_markdown %} #}

{% block entry_posts %}
  <div class="post">
    <h2><a href="{% url "entry" slug=object.slug %}">{{ object.title }}</a></h2>
    <p class="meta">
      {{ object.created }} |
      Tagged under {{  object.tags.all|join:", " }}
    </p>
    {{ object.body }}
  </div>

  <form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %} 
    {{form}}

  <input type="submit" value="Post Comment" class="btn btn-default">
  </form>

  <div class="post">

    <strong>COMMENTS</strong> 
    <hr/>
    {% for comment in entrypost.comments.all %}
    {% if comment.approve %}
    <div class="comment">
      <strong>{{ comment.name}}| created:{{comment.created}}</strong>
      <p>{{comment.comment|linebreaks}}</p>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% empty %}
    <p> no comments :)</p>

    {% endfor %}

  </div>



{% endblock %}
```

Please Kindly Tell me where am wrong cause when ever i run server i cant see the Comment field to input comment i only get to see the post comment button. I kindly welcome contributions to help solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

You use `{{comment_form}}` in your template.

But you render like that `return render(request,'post.html',{"form":comment_form,})`.

In your template you need to call it just with `{{form}}` because that is what you pass.

```
<form method="POST" action="">{% csrf_token %} 
{{form}}
```

You also have to instantiate the comment_form without
  `if request.method == "POST":` because the form needs to be defined first. Just remove it. Then everything should work.

Comment: Thank you Aaron that's true but when I rendered as {{form}} it still doesn't display the comment field..

Comment: Just not the comment field or nothing ?

Comment: just the comment field